# Php sort by filename

Tags: php, sorting

I have this code

```
if($dateOrder){
    $order = array(filemtime($filter_files[0]));
    for($i=1;$i<$maxnr+1;$i++){
        array_push($order,filemtime($filter_files[$i]));
    }
    array_multisort($order,SORT_DESC,SORT_NUMERIC,$filter_files,SORT_ASC,SORT_NUMERIC);
}
}
//end get image files
```

How to make possible sort order by filename? For example

picture1 , picture2 , picture3 picture10 , picture11

Comment: Are the filenames always in the format some <string> followed by some <number> ? If that is the case then you can split each filename into two parts - first part is a seq of chars and the 2nd part is an integer. First you need to sort all the filenames by the first key and then with a group where all keys are same you need to sort by the second part which is number.

Comment: yes, all the images are the same string and incremental numbers. Are you saying that , the code i have is already good?  Can you make an example of your proposal? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code as per my proposal. The difference from your code is the usage of array_multisort method. PHP [array_multiosrt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) expects single dimension non assoc arrays as its first and second dimension and then the whole data array as the last argument.

```
<?php
    $dateOrder = true;
    if($dateOrder){
        /*$order = array(filemtime($filter_files[0]));
        for($i=1; $i<$maxnr+1; $i++){
            array_push($order,filemtime($filter_files[$i]));
        }*/
        $order = array('picture1', 'picture2', 'picture20', 'picture9', 'picture3', 'picture10', 'picture11');
        //array_multisort($order,SORT_DESC,SORT_NUMERIC,$filter_files,SORT_ASC,SORT_NUMERIC);
        $names = array();
        for($i=0; $i<count($order); $i++) {
            preg_match('/^(.+?)(\d+)$/', $order[$i], $matches);
            $names[] = array($matches[1], $matches[2]);
        }

        $name = array();
        $number = array();
        foreach ($names as $key => $row) {
            $name[$key]  = $row[0];
            $number[$key] = $row[1];
        }
        array_multisort($name, SORT_ASC, $number, SORT_NUMERIC, $names);
        $output = array();
        foreach ($names as $row) {
            $output[] = $row[0] . $row[1];
        }
        print_r($output);
    }

    ?>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/228599)